Expected Time to Cross a Boundary in a Random Walk with Uniform Steps
Suppose we have a random walk where each step's distance $ X \in N$ is drawn from a uniform distribution:
$$X \sim \text{Uniform}\{1,\dots,n\}.$$
Each step takes exactly 1 second, and we denote by $ T$ the time (in seconds) it takes for the cumulative sum of steps to first exceed the boundary $n$. That is:
$$T = \min \left\{ t : \sum_{i=1}^t X_i > n \right\},$$
where $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables drawn from $ \text{Uniform}\{1,\dots,n\}$.
My reasoning is as follows:
1)The expectation of a single step distance is:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{n}{2}.
   $$
2) After $2$ steps, the expected cumulative distance is:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^2 X_i\right] = 2 \cdot \frac{n}{2} = n.
$$
Thus, it seems intuitive that the expected time $\mathbb{E}[T]$ to cross the boundary $n$ is:
$$
\mathbb{E}[T] = 2.
$$
Is this reasoning correct? If not, what is the correct value of $\mathbb{E}[T]$, and how can it be derived formally?

Your reasoning is not quite correct. This is because $T$ and $X_i's$ are dependent random variables. The correct approach can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214399/summing-0-1-uniform-random-variables-up-to-1

could the contrast between the uniform distribution over  $(0,1)$ and $[0,n]$, such as implications of Kantor's theorem, influence the result?

Yes, adding up discrete random variables makes it a different problem, but that different problem has also been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3927657/

Clarification question: when you say Uniform$(0,n)$, do you mean that $X$ is equally likely to be any number in the set ${1,\dots,n-1}$? Or did you intend the set ${1,\dots,n}$?

$X$ , the distance of a step, is equally likely to be any number in the set {1, …, n}, where n is a natural number representing the upper bound.
thank you for the link above , it make sense.
